# Android set preferences from XML with PreferenceManager

Tags: android, xml, sharedpreferences

I am trying to get preferences from XML but without using a PreferenceActivity.
I just want to load from the file when my Main activity is created and toast a value from preferences. But the problem is that the toast is empty (null?). I have a class that load the preferences.

Here is the onCreate method of the Main Activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Preferences prefs = new Preferences();
}
```

Preferences class (only the constructor...)

```
public Preferences(Context context) {
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(context, "MyPrefs", 0, R.xml.preferences, false);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("MyPrefs", 0);
    Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    String myValue = sharedPreferences.getString("myKey", null); // I don't know if null is OK
    Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), myValue, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

And the XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <Preference android:key="myKey" android:defaultValue="hello" />
</PreferenceScreen>
```

The first time I launch the app, I would like the default value to be set. So here I want the app to toast "hello" while I haven't set the value with editor.putString(key, value).

Do you know what could be wrong?
Thanks

Comment: you should be calling Preferences class as 'Preferences prefs = new Preferences(this);'

Comment: I tried but didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are programming in java. By suns convention I think you are obliged to use config.propeties file.

I will give a quick and full tutorial to get you going in this matter. I really recommend you using this method cause most of programmers do like that.

I will give you a quick tutorial how to make this file. Where to put it. And how to get data from it.

Begin.

Put a file config.properties into assets folder:
[image]

SAMPLE of config.properties

```
domain=@domain.com.pl
errorTextColor=\#FF0000
serverPort=1234
```

Method how to access and retrieve data from config.properties

public static String getConfigurationPropertiesValue(String value,
         Context context) {
      try {
         Resources resources = context.getResources();
         AssetManager assetManager = resources.getAssets();

```
     try {
        InputStream inputStream = assetManager.open("config.properties");
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.load(inputStream);
        return properties.getProperty(value);
     } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("getConfigurationPropertiesValue",
              "Failed to open config property file");
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return null;
```

}

Literature:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.properties
http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-properties-file-examples/

**EDIT:**

You can also use sharedPreferences to have more control over data like adding data/deleting data/update data. SharedPreferences are more like a SQLite database of android with a nice api to use so you don't really need to know the location of database or SQL.

In order to use it you need to create your data. You only need to do this once. **Or more if user decides that he has an urge to clean you app data from settings -> applications.**

Creating data:

```
   public static void create(Context cw) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = cw.getSharedPreferences(
            ANDROID_MESSENGER, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      editor.putBoolean("isRegistered", false);
      editor.putString("phoneNumber", null);
      editor.putString("callingCode", null);
      String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
      editor.putString("token", uuid);

      editor.putBoolean("internetOnly", false);
      editor.putBoolean("logToDev", true);
      editor.putBoolean("dataTransfer", true);
      Log.i("create", "Generating Token: " + uuid);
      editor.commit();
   }
```

Accesing existing data:

```
   public static String getToken(Context cw) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = cw.getSharedPreferences(
            ANDROID_MESSENGER, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
      return sharedPreferences.getString("token", null);
   }
```

Updating data:

```
   public static void setPhoneNumber(Context cw, String phoneNumber) {
      SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = cw.getSharedPreferences(
            ANDROID_MESSENGER, Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
      SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
      editor.putString("phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
      editor.commit();
   }
```

For an mechanism that will check if data exist or if user deleted it you can use something simple like an additional variable that should be true if all your data is configured. Or there should be an checked method from appshared preferences for that.

Cheers!

Comment: And can I access the file config.properties directly from the file manager of the phone? Where is it located? (I mean other location that in the apk)

Comment: I don't think so. You probably can't access it via file manager cause it is packed into the installation. Config.properties file is for data that will never change and is constant. If you want to get some method to easy get data from android database and change it you are looking for "android sharedPreferences". It is something like a config.properties but you can change data there. If you wish I will give you full example from my code.

Comment: Yes I am interested in your code. I really am beginner and any example could be very practical. Thnks

Comment: I will edit my original post in a few minutes to give you another example.

Comment: It's very nice spending your time helping. Thanks for your code above, I will throw a eye and try to use it properly!

Comment: Not a problem :) I just copy the code from my actual project here so it does not take much time for me ;)

Answer (score 0):

I tried for a long time and found a solution for this :-)
Just a "Preference" is not being recognized by android. Though i don't know why.

If you change it as a Any of the tag like "EditTextPreference" or "CheckboxPreference" its working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_HOMESCREEN_TITLE"
                android:defaultValue="Home Screen"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_ADMIN_BUTTON"
                android:defaultValue="Admin"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_PLAYER_BUTTON"
                android:defaultValue="Player"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_SAVE_BUTTON"
                android:defaultValue="Save"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_CANCEL_BUTTON"
                android:defaultValue="Cancel"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_SERVER_SETUP_IP"
                android:defaultValue="IP:"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_SERVER_SETUP_PORT"
                android:defaultValue="Port:"/>
    <EditTextPreference android:key="CLIENT_SERVER_SETUP_TITLE"
                android:defaultValue="Server Setup"/>
</PreferenceScreen>
```